# Error: GET http://localhost:5000/api/notes/fetchallnotes 401 (Unauthorized) and TypeError: notes.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deployment, react-fullstack

*I am working on a React application where I am fetching notes from an API. However, I am encountering two errors:

1. GET http://localhost:5000/api/notes/fetchallnotes 401 (Unauthorized): This error indicates that the request to fetch notes is unauthorized. I have tried including the access token in the request headers, but the error persists.
2. TypeError: notes.map is not a function: This error occurs in the Notes.js file when I attempt to iterate over the notes array. However, the useEffect hook ensures that the getNotes function is called and the notes array is populated before the render.
   Additional Information:

- I am using React and the context API for state management.
- The relevant code snippets are provided below:
  NoteState.js:

- 

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

import noteContext from "../Context/notes/noteContext";
import Noteitem from "./Noteitem";
import AddNote from "./AddNote";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const Notes = (props) => {
  const context = useContext(noteContext);
  let navigate = useNavigate();
  const { notes, getNotes, editNote } = context;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (localStorage.getItem("token")) {
      getNotes();
    } else {
      navigate("/");
    }
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);

  // ...

  return (
    <>
      {/* ... */}
      <div className="row my-3">
        <h2>Your Notes</h2>
        <div className="container mx-2">
          {notes.length === 0 && "No notes to display."}
        </div>
        {notes.map((note) => {
          return (
            <Noteitem
              key={note._id}
              updateNote={updateNote}
              note={note}
              showAlert={props.showAlert}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Notes;
```

*Note.js:*

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

import noteContext from "../Context/notes/noteContext";
import Noteitem from "./Noteitem";
import AddNote from "./AddNote";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const Notes = (props) => {
  const context = useContext(noteContext);
  let navigate = useNavigate();
  const { notes, getNotes, editNote } = context;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (localStorage.getItem("token")) {
      getNotes();
    } else {
      navigate("/");
    }
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);

  // ...

  return (
    <>
      {/* ... */}
      <div className="row my-3">
        <h2>Your Notes</h2>
        <div className="container mx-2">
          {notes.length === 0 && "No notes to display."}
        </div>
        {notes.map((note) => {
          return (
            <Noteitem
              key={note._id}
              updateNote={updateNote}
              note={note}
              showAlert={props.showAlert}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Notes;
```

Comment: for 1. How you are adding the access token?

Comment: 2. add your context code